# I Customized UserStore and now SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-identity

I created my own UserStore which does exactly as I want. I have seeded a User and that works (password hashes etc). But when I go to login I always get the SignInStatus.Failure

The only difference I can immediatly think of is that my UserName (from IUser) is not an email however I have changed all the validation to make that not required as an email.

Not sure what code snippets to put here so ask away.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I've tried making a second account using the same password and noticed the PasswordHash is different yet I have no salt stored? Is it expected a salt to be stored? I would have expected the PasswordHash to be idential if I am not storing anything else.

Comment: Are you sure that the password you set in the seed method is compliant with all password requirements? That happened to me once and was hard to spot ...

Comment: @ToaoG Yep I have checked that, tried multiple passwords.